# Client Side equivalent for Windows.open('ByteStream') functionality which could interpret response type and render?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, internet-explorer, pdf

I have a PDF byte stream retrieved post web services call, Which is of content type: "application/pdf" - I'm trying to load this in the browser in the same page post ajax call. If a new window is opened, based on the content type the corresponding application is invoked(Working Fine)... Is there a utility which can do the similar parsing that opening a new window does. Any JS utility which support the functionality in IE8. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to make the browser show the PDF in general, or how to specifically open the external PDF viewer app to show the PDF? Answer to first is to not use AJAX, but open URL in a new Window. I believe that answer to second is that you can't.

Comment: I don't want the browser to do the conversion of the byte array to pdf based on the content type available in response rather need that to be done using JavaScript by itself.

Comment: No conversion necessary, the bytes received *are* the PDF. However, you can't save that to file, and you can't open a PDF viewer. Only the browser can do that, for security reasons.